# Groovy - compare percentage values

Tags: groovy, percentage

I have this list:

```
 def list = ['100%', '25%', '80%', '1%', '100%', '12%', '100%', '75%', '20%', '100%']
```

I want to use this piece of code:

```
for (i in list){
    if (i < 90){
       println 'failed'
    }
}
```

How to remove those percentages, to get just integer values so I could do a comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> def list = [100%, 25%, 80%, 1%, 100%, 12%, 100%, 75%, 20%, 100%]

That isn't valid Groovy code.

You could do something like this...

```
def list = [1.0, .25, .80, .01, 1.0, .12, 1.0, .75, .20, 1.0]

list.sort()
```

You could also do something like this...

```
def list = ['100%', '25%', '80%', '1%', '100%', '12%', '100%', '75%', '20%', '100%']

def result = list.collect { it[0..-2].toInteger() }.sort()
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what this means:  it[0..-2]?

Comment: "Could you explain to me what this means: it[0..-2]?" - In this context, since it is being applied to a `String` it means create a new `String` that begins with the first character of `it` (index 0) and ends with the second to the last character (-2), so `"75%"[0..-2]` would evaluate to `"75"`.  It is a way to remove the percent sign without having to interrogate the other characters looking for a percent sign.  There are a number of ways to accomplish that.  You could use something like `it - '%'` and that would work fine, but then we have to look at individual characters to find the `%`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way:

```
def list = ['100%', '25%', '80%', '1%', '100%', '12%', ]

list = list.collect{ ( it - '%' ).toInteger() }
// or
list = list*.minus( '%' )*.toInteger()

assert Integer == list*.getClass().unique().first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```java
def list = ['100%', '25%', '80%', '1%', '100%', '12%', '100%', '75%', '20%', '100%']
list = list.stream()
    .map{ row -> row.replace("%", "").toInteger()}
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).